# Given a measure of some subsets, how can you determine the number of sets in the sigma algebra?

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, measurable-sets

I was given a question that I can't wrap my head around.

Given a measure space ($X, \Omega,\mu$), with $X$ = {1,2,3, ... 16 }, we have

$C_1$ = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 }

$C_2$ = {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}

$C_3$ = {1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14}

$C_4$ = {3,4,7,8,11,12,15,16}

$C$ denotes the field generated by {$C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$}. We then let $\Omega$ = $\sigma[C]$.

With $\mu(C_\mathscr i) = 1/2, 1\le\mathscr i\le4$, and $\mu(C_1\cap C_3) = 1/4$, how can I show that $\hat{\Omega_\mu} = \Omega$, with $2^4 = 16$ sets?

I have tried equating the measures of the subsets to 1, but I do not know how it will determine the number of sets in $\Omega$. Additionally, I suppose that the proving of the completeness of $\Omega$ (hence it being equal to $\hat{\Omega_\mu}$) will come after I get the number of subsets in the sigma algebra? Please enlightment me. Thank you so much!

Comment: $\mu$ would seem to be irrelevant here, you only care about $\Omega$.  I would start by looking for subsets $S$ that "always go together" in the sense that for all $C_i$, $S \cap C_i$ is either $C_i$ or $\emptyset$.  $\{1,2\}$ is such an set in your example.  These sets are always preserved by the operations in a sigma algebra (union, intersection, complement) and so any element of the sigma algebra will either have the whole set or none of the set.  Then for the purpose of counting the sigma algebra, these sets act like a single element.

Comment: For this small example you could simply brute-force it. Take the  intersection and union of each pair of sets, and the complement of each set, and put it in a list.  Keep doing this until you can no longer enlarge the list, and you have a sigma algebra.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I'm sorry I do not quite get the purpose of acquiring subsets S. If I understand correctly, acquiring such sets will help me count such elements of a subset (for example, 1and 2) as one. I generated the smallest sigma algebra and acquired 8 "pairs". Better yet, I have also observed that there a 4 sets of fours that are always together such as 1, 2, 5, 6 and 11, 12, 15, 16. These four do not intersect. Will they count as individual elements and therefore, the number of elements in the sigma algebra will be 2^n =2^4 = 16?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.  Although you would presumably need to prove that this method works.

Comment: @JairTaylor, thank you for that! Tried on a different measure space and so far it works. May I ask if there is a theory associated with this? Although I get the process, I am not quite sure what I would cite or say when proving this.

Comment: OK, I added some detail in an answer.

Comment: @AppliedTheoreticals Would you mind explaining in a bit more detail what you did to arrive at 2^n = 16 in your comment above.  ( I didn't follow what the pairs in quotes meant ).  I'm thinking that you did what Jair Taylor suggested in the comment right above that comment but, if you could get me started doing that, if that's what you did,  it's appreciated. I'll worry about jair's full answer below when I'm more free. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @markleeds 1/2 I may need to answer in two parts. One of my ideas for solving this was using an observation on the set X (which I was skeptical of until Jair Taylor also suggested it and even gave detailed answers. Kudos!)  The observation was that the elements within X did are pairwise disjoint (meaning that they don't have any intersections with each other) and why the 16 elements are each treated as individuals. Now when you look at C1-C4, you can see numbers that are always together. The first suggestion was to find pairs that were always together, hence "pairs", such as 1 and 2.

Comment: @markleeds 2/2 However, for this collection, the numbers came in fours. Indeed when you generate the sigma-algebra (which has 16 elements), there are four groups of four numbers. These are {1,2,5,6}, {3,4,7,8}, {9,10,13,14}, and {11,12,15,16}. You can also see that they are disjoint. Hence, these four can be treated as "individual" elements. This is where the 2^n = 2^4 = 16 came from. The rest of the proof was detailed by Jair Taylor in an answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Applied Theoreticals: I will print above out and read carefully. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of subsets of some finite set $X$, and let $\Omega$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated from $\mathcal{C}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of subsets of $S \subseteq X$ that are "indivisible" in the sense that they always go together as a group, or not at all, in any $C \in \mathcal{C}$, and that are as big as possible. More formally, define $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of subsets of $S$ so that

1. For any set $C \in \mathcal{C}$, either $S \cap C = \emptyset$ or $S \cap C = C$.
2. There is no proper superset of $S$ that has property (1).

I claim that $|\Omega| = 2^{|\mathcal{A}|}$. I'll give an outline for the proof and leave the details to you.

The reason is that we have a bijection $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow \Omega$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})$ is the power set of $\mathcal{A}$, given by $f(T) = \bigcup_{A \in T} A$. To see this, we must show

1. $f(T) \in \Omega$ for any $T \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})$. To show this, first show that any $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is an intersection of elements of $C$; specifically, $A = \cap_{C \in \Omega, a \subseteq C} C$. That follows because of property (2) (prove this!).  Then $f(T)$ is a union of intersections of elements of $C$ and so belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra.
2. $f$ is surjective.  To see this, prove that the image of $f$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains $\mathcal{C}$.  It follows from the definition of a generated $\sigma$-algebra that the image of $f$ contains $\Omega$. (do you see why?)
3. $f$ is injective. We must show that if $f(T_1) = f(T_2)$ then $T_1 = T_2$. Hint: Pick an element of $f(T_1)$, say $x$; then there must be some $A_1 \in T_1$ and $A_2 \in T_2$ so that $x \in A_1$, $x \in A_2$. Show $A_1 = A_2$ and continue, inductively.